# How does this statement ( answer += newSum == k;) work?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to understand how the code below works in JavaScript.

`answer += newSum == k;`

Answer (score 1):

The numerical equivalent of the boolean `true` is 1 and `false` equals 0

Hence, the above statement will increment 1 if `newsum` equals `k`, and increments 0 if not

you can test this by the following code

```js
a = 3

console.log( a+true ) // returns 4
console.log( a+false ) // returns 3

a += (1==1)  //same as a+=true

console.log(a) // returns 4
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a **number** to a **boolean** the boolean will convert to a number
Here is an exstensive explanation on how this works: [codeburst.io](https://codeburst.io/javascript-why-does-3-true-4-and-7-other-tricky-equations-9dd13cb2a92a)

```
false -> 0
true -> 1
```

If you don't know what += does

```
a += b
```

is the same as

```
a = a + b
```

When you try this

```js
var answer = 5
    answer += true
console.log(answer) // 6

var answer = 5
    answer = answer + true
console.log(answer) // 6
```

you can see it is like doing 5 + 1

now if you replace true with

```
newSum == k
```

this returns either true or false

so if newSum == k then you add 1 to answer else answer stays the same.

You were not specific about what part of the code you didn't understand hence my extensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the value of the boolean. `true = 1` and `false = 0`

So if `newSum == k` is `true`, it will add `1` to `answer` since the value of true is 1.  If it is false, it will add 0 since the value of false is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Let answer = 1 and newSum=4 and K=5;

then the statment answer += newSum == k; (1=1+4==5) will return true and the value of answer is 1.

== this will work as boolean true = 1 and false = 0
so if newSum==K answer get 1 and if not answer get 0 and if you did not initialize answer as answer=0 you will get NaN means undefined

Answer (score 0):

Given:  answer += newsum ==k

Here variables are:

- answer
- newsum
- k

Operators are: += and ==

How compiler works:
It scans input from left to right and modifies the data accordingly
and then it assigns the value
Note: It is different when BODMAS or PADMAS comes into scenario

In step 1: answer += newsum means
answer = answer + new sum

the sum of answer and newsum will be assigned into answer

In step 2: answer == k means
it will check weather the value in k is equal to answer(updated value in answer)

Example:
answer=2,newsum=3,k=5 it goes this way

step:1 : answer = answer +newsum

```
       2=2+3
        5(now value of answer=5)
```

step:2 :5 == 5

```
     It checks weather 5=5 or not
     if yes returns true or do the function or else false i.e skips the function
     in this case true
```

example code:

```js
 var answer=2;
 var newSum=3;
 var k=5;

if(answer += newSum == k){

window.alert("k and answer are same");

}
else{window.alert("not same");}
```